# Program to get rtsp stream and dump on virtual camera?

Tags: linux, video, streaming

I'm looking for a Linux program that gets a rtsp stream and channel it into a virtual camera device. The majority that I've found does the opposite get from a virtual camera to be streamed on a RTSP server. I've found ffmpeg but under a very specific situation it doesn't work but I can see the camera's stream in vlc. Unfortunately with VLC you can't configure the device output like /dev/video1 so I'm looking for similar softwares.